# How to push docker compose to docker hub

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry

i have serveral services in my docker-compose file, it looks like this:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: ./
    command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers 2 --worker-connections 5000 --timeout 6000 manage:app
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app/
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static_files
    expose:
      - 5000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.4.1
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: mongod
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    environment:
      MONGODB_DATA_DIR: /data/db
      MONDODB_LOG_DIR: /dev/null
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: 
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 
    volumes:
      - mongodbdata:/data/db

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static_files
    ports:
      - 5001:8000
    depends_on:
      - web


volumes:
  mongodbdata: 
  static_volume:
```

and i have public repository on my docker hub account, i want to push all images in my app to that repo, anyone can help?

Comment: When `docker-compose` builds an image, it will have name. Just `docker tag` and `docker push` those images like any other image.

Comment: how about my mongodb and nginx, wil it be pushed too? @larsks

Comment: @Mamen no, just the one that you currently push

Comment: so if i want to build and run my project from docker hub repo, i have to pull the image and run the docker compose file above, is that right? @AndrzejSydor

Comment: @Mamen yes, in the case to build and run, just run the Docker Compose. The images will be pulled automatically.

Comment: Note that you can't push volume content, local files, or the `docker-compose.yml` file itself; you'll need to delete some `volumes:` for this to work on another system, and it won't have your current system's MongoDB data or the alternate version of the static files you mount into your containers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should add image names to your services, including your docker hub id, e.g.:

```yaml
services:
  web:
    build: ./
    image: docker-hub-id/web:latest
    ...
```

Now, you can just call `docker-compose push`.

See [docker-compose push](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/push/)